# How to set "environmentVariables": {} in .aws templates.json file in vscode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, environment, sam

I am using VSCode to develop, test AWS Lambda functions.
I could not find any help on how to set "environmentVariables": {} in .aws/templates.json file, so that my lambda function picks them up.

Comment: Environment variables will be done on local by adding the system environment variables. But when moved to prod it is done iusing credential in Jenkins. Usually it will not pick from any file

Comment: Not necessarily true. Eclipse has its way on how to set environment variables that it passes to the runtime.
VSCode too has its way to set these, and there is a place holder in templates.json file. Issue is there is no documentation that explains in what format they should be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aws-toolkit-vscode group provided me the answer on their github issue board.
Go to this link on how to set environment variables.

https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/795